# How did the 4th of July "Salute to America" military parade compare to France's (regular one) on Bastille Day, numerically?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military, france, comparative-politics

Trump's decision to have a military parade on the 4th of July last year was criticized as being out of character for the US and [even costly](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/07/03/politics/military-concerns-trump-july-4th-event/index.html).

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastille_Day_military_parade), France regularly conducts such a parade on Bastille Day (14th of July), and it might be the largest such parade in Western Europe:

> The parade involves around 8,800 soldiers (6,800 on foot, the rest are crew members or cavalrymen), 360 vehicles, 240 horses and more than 80 planes and helicopters.[27][28][29] It is the biggest regular military parade in Western Europe.[citation needed]

(Based on the citations, those figures seem to apply to the 2011 parade, and I don't know how much they vary from year to year.)

Leaving aside the controversy due to lack of US tradition in this regard, in numerical terms, was the US parade bigger or smaller than the French one? I'm asking in part because in 2018 Trump more or less jokingly [told](https://www.vox.com/the-big-idea/2018/2/12/17003600/trump-military-parade-bastille-day-washington) Macron he was going to "top" France's parade.

Comment: How is this a political question?

Comment: @CGCampbell: questions about politicians' egos (and promises) are within scope. https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: OK, I can see that it is, by the current rules, on-topic/scope. However, please think about possible edits, as it appears that two other people agree that this is a questionable question (I cannot up-vote my own comment).